# Could not find view "index" in view catalog

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I need a client to give the page. I made a simple node.js server.

Project structure

```
| web-site (folder)
    | package.json (files)
    | package-lock.json (files)
    | node_modules (folder)
    ...
    | src (folder)
          | index.js (files)
          | routers (folder)
              | routesr.js (files)
          | views (folder)
              | index.hbs (files)
          ...
```

Index.js file contents.

```
import express from 'express'
import routers from './routers/routers';

const port = process.env.PORT || 8081;
const router = express();

router.set('views', __dirname + '/views/');
router.set('view engine', 'hbs');

router.use(express.static('./../public'));
router.use(routers);

router.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

export default router;
```

routers.js file contents.

```
import express from 'express'

const router = express();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const peopleList = getRandomList();
    res.render('index', { people: peopleList });
});

export default router;

const getRandomList = () => {
    const list = ['ada', 'turing', 'lovelace', 'neumann', 'gracehopper'];
    const limit = Math.floor(Math.random() * (list.length - 1 - 0) + 0);
    return list.slice(limit);
};
```

index.hbs file contents.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <ul>
        {{#each people}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

When I open a route `http://localhost:8081` in a browser, I get an error

> Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "C:\Users\user\Documents\website\views"

Why does my server not see the index.hbs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
router.set('views', __dirname + '/views/');
```

to

```
router.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/'));
```

Comment: I tried this solution, it did not help. It seems to me that the problem is that the server is looking for a file along the path `C:\Users\user\Documents\website\views` but should search along the path `C:\Users\user\Documents\website\src\views`

Comment: try add `'/src/views/'` instead of `'/views/'`

Comment: I tried, the error remains the same `Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "C:\Users\user\Documents\website\views"`

Comment: what `console.log(__dirname)` returns from `Index.js` file?
Also you could try removing first slash from `'/views/'` like
`router.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/'));`

Comment: He's returns `C:\Users\user\Documents\website\src`

Comment: in this case i think problem with first slash `/`. I edited the answer